# How to extract column name and data types from Glue Dynamic Dataframe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, pyspark

I am trying to extract column names and data types from Glue dynamic frame and wanted to use them in spark sql.
For ex:

```
 persons = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
         database="legislators",
         table_name="customer_table")
```

persons.printSchema()

The output is

root
|-- cust_no: long
|-- name: string
|-- address: string
|-- zip: long

How to extract column names and data types from dynamic frame. I wanted to trim only strings, not longs.
I wanted to use the columns in spark sql

```
spark.sql(""" SELECT cust_no, trim(name),trim(address),zip....""")
```

Please advise how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a spark dataframe and apply the dftypes method.

```
persons.toDF().dtypes
```

Using this method you get a list of tuples containing the column and respective data type inside your dataframe.

```
[('cust_no', 'long'),('name', 'string'),('address','string'),('zip','long')]
```